# PubNub WebRTC library - how to end session

Tags: webrtc, pubnub

I'm using PubNub's WebRTC library to start a WebRTC session and show the local video stream. How can I end the session, unsubscribe and remove the stream again?

```
var phone = window.phone = PHONE({
    number        : 12345,
    publish_key   : '...',
    subscribe_key : '...',
    ssl: true
}); 

var ctrl = window.ctrl = CONTROLLER(phone);

phone.ready(function(){
    ctrl.addLocalStream(document.getElementById("vid-thumb"))
});
```

Comment: Did you try `hangup` - https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/#webrtc-session-hangup

Answer (score 0):

#### WebRTC Session Hangup

`session.hangup()`

> End the session right now.
>   The `'ended'` callback will fire for both connected parties on either side of the call.

```
$("#hangup").click(function(){
    // End the call
    session.hangup();
});
```

#### WebRTC Phone Hangup

`phone.hangup()`

> There are two ways to hangup WebRTC calls.
>   You can use the phone-level method `phone.hangup()`
>   which will hangup all calls at once.

Or you can use the session-level method `session.hangup()`
which will only hangup that call session.

```
// hangup all calls
phone.hangup();

// hangup single session
session.hangup();
```

> Source: https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/#webrtc-session-hangup